# mysql query to import data from dump to existing data and overwrite new entry

Tags: sql, import, mysql

I want to import new DUMP file to my old database which has same schema. I want to overwrite if there is anychange in record with dump file record I am importing and want to add new records. I dont want to delete the existing records in the DB I am gonna import.

Comment: Can you change INSERT to REPLACE in the dump file?
"REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted."

Comment: @TerjeD. how can I replace, I still have to take DUMP of my 13 GB data to import in to 60 GB data. but that 13 GB data has latest records and some records in between which are new, 60 GB is old data where I will be copying dump of 13 GB data, now how can I use replace in the dump file?

Comment: Do a search and replace using your favourite text editor.

Comment: @terjeD. What if dump file is too large and is on server and not on local, is there any way to import so that it can overwrite with latest record?

Comment: It turns out that mysqldump has an option `--replace` that generates dump files containing replace statements instead of insert statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the dump file using mysqldump, you can give it the option --replace,which generates a dump file containing replace statements instead of insert statements.
When this dump file is loaded into MySQL, records that matches primary or unique keys in the database will replace the old ones, while records not matching existing keys will be inserted.

Comment: What will be the mysql comand cause I dont see --replace on this page. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysqldump.html.

Comment: The --replace option in mysqldump was introduced in version 5.1.3. Using older versions is see no other method than editing the dump file to change `insert` into `replace`.

Comment: Wondering what the update command do, instead of replace, coz I was getting some error while i wastesting in my local DB when I was just playing around with data, that i can not delete foreign key row... some thing like that

Comment: Assuming that the data in your dump file is consistent, you can try to `set foreign_key_checks=0` before doing the replace operation.